# Updating a table with the changes made from another table

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, cursor, update

I am trying to do updates to a source table from another table that has a like field (propertyid). I am trying to update all of the fields in the source table. I have gotten the outcome I want with ModelBuilder, but the model is inefficient because I would have to add a Field Calculator tool for every field that I am trying to update. Here is what I have written, it is running but nothing happens in my output.

```
import arcpy

# Define workspace

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\CartoFront\Desktop\Updates\Updates.gdb"

#Define Feature Classes
fc1 = "Update_121316_test"
fc2 = "ChiMetroJoin12012016clean"

#Define Fields
fc1_fields = ["*", "propertyid"]
fc2_fields = ["*","propertyid"]

#Define Values
fc1_value= "*"
fc2_value = "*"

cur = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, fc1_fields)

for row in cur:
    cur2 = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc2, fc2_fields)
    for row2 in cur2:
        if row[1] == row2[1]:
            if row[0] == fc1_value:
                row2[0] = fc2_value
                cur2.updateRow(row2)
del row, cur, row2, cur2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have this written, you're probably not actually matching the property IDs, but instead whatever appears as the 2nd thing in the list pulled up by the '*'. The star is pulling every field in your table in order, followed by your propertyid, which will now be the last item in a long list (actually tuple).

To see what I mean, do this test. Open your attribute table for feature class #1 and select just the first couple of rows. Then in your python window run this:

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, fc1_fields):
    print row
```

This will show you exactly which fields you're working with and what order they're in. You need to specify the exact order of your matching fields to make this work. Ditto for feature class 2 as well.

Also, you probably don't want to match up row values with literal '*', unless you actual have stars in your table. You should list your fields that you want to update, starting with your matching field (propertyid):

```
fc1_value = ['propertyid', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']
fc2_value = ['propertyid', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']
```

For your cursors, it's not a great idea to remake a cursor in every cycle of a for-loop. This is very wasteful of your computer's resources and can crash. My preferred style is to consume the first cursor in a list or set, and then access the items in the list or set for the second cursor. That strategy looks something like this:

```
curList = list(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, fc1_value))

curDict = {}
for item in curList:
    curDict[item[0]] = item[1:5]

with acrpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc2, fc2_fields) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        if row[0] in curDict: 
            row[1] = curDict[row[0]][0]
            row[2] = curDict[row[0]][1]
            row[3] = curDict[row[0]][2]
            row[4] = curDict[row[0]][3]
            cur.updateRow(row)
```

*Edit - The initial search cursor return is rearranged into a dictionary for easy lookup. The keys of the dictionary are the property ids, matched with a tuple holding the corresponding field values. When property id's match in the Update cursor v. dictionary, the values in the dictionary are grabbed and used to update rows in the table.

Comment: Would this be something I should do with indexing the field that I want to work with. So basically, if I am understanding correctly, I should change fc1_fields to the index or order of the propertyid?

Comment: Right. The row[1] and row2[1] are indexing the tuples returned by the cursors in each cycle of the loop. You need to figure out what index position your propertyIDs are sitting at in both cursors and match those up. Especially because you sent your propertyID to the last index position, I'll bet they're not sitting in index [1].

Comment: You can rearrange the positions of things in the tuples any way you want, you just have to make sure that you match up the right things.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I am also wondering once it gets to the if row[0] == fc1_value, do I have to do something to the tuple there to make sure that it iterates through the entire table to check if all the fields are equal to the fc1_value?

Comment: I was a little confused by that last part. I thought maybe you had stars in your table or something. You're matching the value held in row[0] with a literal *. What you should probably do is make a list of all the fields want to read/update with your property id as the first item. Store these lists in your fc1_fields and fc2_fields instead of the stars. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The code is returning TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing when I try to run it. Would you have any input on why this is?

Comment: Should I switch the indexing to the actually field names?

Comment: If I'm interpreting your question correctly, no you don't want to use actual field names instead of row[1], row[2], etc. This has to do with the general functioning of for-loops. Row becomes the place holder temp variable representing the collection of field-values in each cycle of the loop.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I see what the issue is now. I'll adjust my answer.